# An Error with SDL_CeateWindow appearing when program started

Tags: c, sdl, assert

The code below initializes an SDL window. Because of bug I can't find `SDL_CreateWindow()` returns `NULL`.

```c
int xwin_init(int w, int h)
{
    int r;
    r = SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    assert(win == NULL);
    win = SDL_CreateWindow("PRG Semester Project",SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, w, h,SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    SDL_SetWindowTitle(win, "PRG SEM");
    SDL_Surface *surface = SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom(icon_32x32_bits,32, 32, 24, 32*3, 0xff, 0xff00,0xff0000, 0x0000);
    SDL_SetWindowIcon(win, surface);
    SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
    return r;
}
```

The error message looks like this:

```
prgsem: xwin_sdl.c:58: xwin_init: Assertion win != NULL' failed`
```

Comment: Please don't make additions to your question in with comments but [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56177681/edit) your question instead.

Comment: It might help if you posted the code that makes that assertion.

Answer (score 0):

While I can't tell you what your problem is, at the very least it is worth checking for errors after initializing video and creating the window. You can use [SDL_GetError](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetError) to do this. A message about an error reported through the SDL library will be accessible through this function, and you can tell when to call it based on the return codes of other SDL functions such as `SDL_Init` in your example.